# text вставляет html код без форматирования

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой js код:

```
$('.dropdown-menu > a').click(function(e){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').text(this.innerHTML);
    $('input[name=method]').val(this.name);
});
```

При клике на определенный элемент в списке, кнопка заменяется этим самым элементом, но вместо нормального кнопка заменяется не форматированным html кодом что на выходе получается такое:

[image: Что выходит на выходе]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как правильно заменить кнопку с форматированным html кодом?

Comment: Для это в jQuery есть метод .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.dropdown-menu > a').click(function(e){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').html(this.innerHTML);
    $('input[name=method]').val(this.name);
});
```